# What is the recommended way to instantiate objects in TYPO3 extensions

Tags: typo3, typo3-8.x

I am assuming extension development with Extbase / Fluid and TYPO3 >= 8.

AFAIK, there are 3 methods of instantiating objects:

1. `new()` as in classic PHP (not recommended)
2. `GeneralUtility::makeInstance()`
3. `$this->objectManager->get()`

I would like to know in which cases it is better to use `makeInstance` or `objectManager::get`. Is there possibly more overhead with using the objectManager?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For use with domain model objects and repositories `objectManager->get` is preferred. As you've pointed out it takes care of injecting dependencies.
Most classes from the core that you will explicitly instantiate don't use dependency injection because they are utilities and services, and they are also meant to be used outside an extbase context.

`MakeInstance` has some extra features over the `new` keyword. It handles singletons and supports `XCLASS`ing.

The special `::class` constant is available since PHP 5.5.0. The core started using it when support for PHP < 5.5 was dropped.